# Atom Nuclide: no Linting no Flow

Tags: atom-editor, eslint, nuclide-editor

Installed Nuclide for Atom, disabled the `linter` per their [instructions](https://nuclide.io/docs/advanced-topics/linter-package-compatibility/) and also I've installed the linter (?) per [their instructions](https://github.com/sprintr/nuclide/blob/master/README.md#installation).  Also I've generated an .eslintrc.js..

```
 module.exports = {
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "plugins": [
   "react"
  ]
};
```

..in my `package.json`, I have the following linters

```
"eslint": "^2.13.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.0.0",
```

**Using Flow**

   `@flow
var foo: number = '123424';`

Using Flow ** sometimes ** works. Half the time Flow works when I start Atom (and restart Flow server), other times not at all. What can one do to make this feature less flaky and work all the time?

**Using Lint**
Doesn't ever work. Apparently Lint will work via Diagnostic feature, but it doesn't. What steps does one need to take to have linting in Nuclide? Thanks!

I have eslint install globally.`v3.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

I went through something similar, so I'll post this finding in response to what could have possibly been going on. I am running OS Sierra @10.12.4 with the most recent version of nuclide, atom, and flow@0.42.0. I'm using flow for a React Native project. I'm also using a linter config I found on npm. I noticed that the script below worked in my package.json with `"flow-bin": "^0.42.0"` in the dev dependency:

`"flow-test": "flow; test $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 2"`

However, the little spinner in the lower right of the editor was showing that it was waiting for flow for a while and then would time out. I came across [this article on this issue](http://speakreact.com/2016/06/05/flow-waiting-for-diagnostics/) and saw that I needed to brew install flow and make sure the ocaml dependencies were properly installed as well (this shows up after the brew install). After doing this, the flow diagnostic feature works even with linter and linter-eslint packages enabled.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to delete my `.atom` folder in my home directory, then re-install all the packages. It was annoying, and I would keep a list of your packages before deleting this folder.

`rm -rf ~/.atom`